# Special Character problem in a PHP page on iPhone

Tags: php

I have a word document (Docx) file, the file name is in the database with spaces, parenthesis etc

When I pull the file name from the database in PHP it looks like this

```
<a href="mydomain.com/16.07%20Platform%203%20(1).docx">Open</a>
```

Which works great on desktop, android mobile.

**But doesn't work on iPhone, shows following error**.
When I rename the file to example 1.docx, it works and opens the docx in iPhone. What should I do as I do not have control on the user file upload.

[image]

Comment: if you don't have control over the filenames, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: You should properly URL-encode the file name. Right now it looks like you neglected to do that (if you did, the ( and )  should have been percent encoded as well, but since they aren’t, you likely did nothing at all in that regard, and the spaces being replaced by %20 is probably the browser itself trying to partly fix this.)

Comment: you can use a route like: yourdomain.com/download?file=urlencode(name) and in your route you urldecode the name and send the file to the user